# PHPMailer() Upload and Attachment Issue

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send an e-mail using `PHPMailer()`. With the e-mail, I am trying to send an attachment. In addition, the attachment is going to be uploaded by the user, thus, an upload button is provided.

```
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" />
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
```

My algorithm is to have the file saved in the `attachments` folder in the server.

```
$target_dir = "/attachments";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }
    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 1000000000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
```

After the upload, I try to attach the file to the e-mail.

```
$mail->addAttachment('attachments/'.$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
```

My problem is that no file is saved in the `attachments` folder and no attachment was sent together with the e-mail. However, I was successful in sending the rest of the e-mail to my intended destination.

Comment: Well obviously if there is no file to attach, then attaching it to the email isn't going to work... Fix your uploads first, then think about the email.

Comment: Are you try to do it on linux or windows? Anyway, try to use absolute path for your targetdir. `/attachment` is on the root level on linux. And you also need to use ['tmp_name']` when you add atachment.